# how can i connect to other hosts other than localhost in nodejs while making connection to the database

Tags: node.js

Nodejs working only with localhost while making connection to the mysql database.how can i connect to other hosts?

this is my code

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var express=require('express');
const app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}))
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
        return res.send({error:true,message:'working'});
})
app.listen(8080,function() {
        console.log('port listening on 8080');
})
const mc=mysql.createConnection({
        host:'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password:'root',
        database:'test'
})
mc.connect();
app.get('/users',function(req,res) {
    mc.query('select * from sample1',function(err,results) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(({status:200,data:results}));
            return res.send({status:200,data:results});
    })
})
app.post('/userslist',function(req,res) {
    var id=req.body.id;
    console.log(id);
    return res.send(id);
})
```

when i change the host address it shows some error

```
port listening on 8080
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.10:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/nodejs/index.js:21:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
```

i don't know for what reason this error is shown .how can i get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Which port host mysql is running ?

Comment: i think port 80

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to adjust the host, port, user, password, database name.

Make sure your have the correct config :

```
const mc=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'root',
    database:'test'
})
```

Comment: how can i adjust the port and host

Comment: when i change localhost as my own system ip it also showing the  same error,but i can aceess the phpmyadmin in browser?